# Finding causality and cross correlation of multiple variables in time series

Tags: time-series, pattern-recognition, cross-correlation

I'm new to time series.

I have 24 variables in a monthly measured time series from 2009 to 2015. The time series measures how much production data that is registered in a ERP system and are intercorrelated some more than others. It has a nice upwards trend for almost all variables.

Being internal company data the variables are measured in a "closed environment" and I know that variables outside the environment has no importance.

Is there a way without using tedious cross correlation for each case to determine the causality and cross correlation for all? I thought of factor analysis but is this possible/reasonable for this time series data?

Essentially I want to get a overview of the relationships with R and make a "basic" easy to use simulation tool in excel.

Comment: I like the question.  Try exploring the literature on time series factor analysis.